# My ceiling fan is sparking even though i have turned its switch off. What to do? Will it cause a fire?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I was sitting in my room when I noticed that the ceiling fan was sparking and causing fumes. I tried turning it off but neither it stopped spining nor sparking. I'm really worried about whether it will cause a fire or something. It stopped only upon switching off the main supply. Pls help me asap.

Comment: Step 1: **leave the breaker turned off**. It's likely that a wire has worked loose and that you've got a short. If you're comfortable doing some DIY electrical work, someone will be along shortly to help, otherwise, you'll want to call in an electrician. In the meantime, please [edit] your post to let us know where in the world you live - there are different electrical systems and the repair work will vary slightly.

Comment: Leave the breaker for the fan off. Has any new work been done lately?  Any new switches, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a lot of new ceiling fans, the "switch" in the box in the wall is nothing more than a wireless transmitter and the fan is permanently wired at the ceiling through the wireless receiver. So if that receiver unit fails shorted, the fan cannot be turned off. If you are not comfortable with electrical work, this is something that will require the services of a qualified electrician.